# Sculpting a human model for animation

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine, sculpting

So I am sculpting a model to future animation. Right now I have the mouth sealed. Its basically just an outline of the mouth, so its like I'm sculpting it closed. My question is, do I have to sculpt the mouth open so that I can animate it in the future for speaking and expressions?? I'll be posting pictures so to get an idea of what I'm trying to say.[image]

Comment: yes, the mouth could be sculpted as closed, but you have to make sure the upper and lower lips are separated from each other

Comment: You will retopoligize it, right?

Comment: Yeah, I plan to retopologize after sculpting. Thanks for the info!